# How can i solve data transferred from slave to master using SPI?

Tags: embedded, atmega

I tried to make a communication between two AVR (ATmega128) using SPI.

Data transferred correctly from master to slave but data transferred wrong from slave to master, the first sampled bit is always wrong.

Slave sends (0X7E) to master but the received data is (0X3F).

Where is the mistake?

#### Code of MASTER

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#define ACK 0x7E

void spi_init_master(void)
{
    DDRB = (1<<0)|(1<<1)|(1<<2);              //Set MOSI, SCK, SS as Output
    PORTB |= 1; 
    SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR0); //Enable SPI, Set as Master, Prescaler: Fosc/16
}

//Function to send and receive data
unsigned char spi_tranceiver(unsigned char data)
{
    PORTB &= ~(1<<0);
    SPDR = data;                       //Load data into the buffer
    while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));       //Wait until transmission complete
    PORTB |= (1<<0);
    return (SPDR);                      //Return received data
}

int main(void)
{
    spi_init_master();                  //Initialize SPI Master
    
    unsigned char data;
    unsigned char ret;
    
    while (1) 
    {
        ret = spi_tranceiver(data);
    }
}
```

#### Code of SLAVE

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
#define ACK 0x7E

void spi_init_slave(void)
{
    DDRB = (1<<3);                                  //MISO as OUTPUT
    SPCR = (1<<SPE);                                //Enable SPI
}

//Function to send and receive data
unsigned char spi_tranceiver(unsigned char data)
{
    SPDR = data;                                  //Load data into buffer
    while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));                  //Wait until transmission complete
    return (SPDR);                                 //Return received data
}


int main(void)
{
    spi_init_slave();                             //Initialize slave SPI
    unsigned char data;
    
    while (1) 
    {
        data = spi_tranceiver(ACK);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know these parts, but they might need more time for SS to go low. Between `PORTB &= ~(1<<0);` and `SPDR = data;`, you have some hundred nanoseconds, assuming a regular low end oscillator. The physical I/O pins might need more time to toggle. Do you get the same issue if you single step through the master code in your debugger?

Comment: Did you use the correct CPOL and CPHA?

Comment: @Lundin thank you for your reply, i put a condition after this line (PORTB &= ~(1<<0);) to make sure the state of this pin is changed but the same problem occurred  ( while( (PORTB & (1<<0)) ); ) i think this is not the problem because the master sends data correctly

Comment: @thebusybee thank you for your reply, i used mode zero data is sampled at rising edge and changed at falling edge

Comment: The master uses an uninitialized variable to send its byte. Probably you edited the source, didn't you?

Comment: And, how do you check the received byte?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to watch the lines? Did you check the signals against your expectations?

Comment: @thebusybee Master takes data from adc channel and sends it to Slave and i display it on LCD

Comment: Well, that does not answer any of the questions in our comments. :-} Please remember to [edit] your question if you have new information. Make sure you took the [tour] and read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is at reloading the data register @SLAVE. In your code this is done via polling. So if you have a high clock speed the slave does not get enough time to reload the register corectly.

Important notice:

> Clock peed of SPI has to be F_CPU/4 on slave (see the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc2467.pdf) on Page 168)

Try to put in a delay at master. So the slave got some time to reload the register:

```c
#define F_CPU ?????????UL  // Clock speed of system in Hz

unsigned char spi_tranceiver(unsigned char data);

#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    // ...
    
    while (1) 
    {
        ret = spi_tranceiver(data);
    }
}

unsigned char spi_tranceiver(unsigned char data)
{
    _delay_ms(10);
    PORTB &= ~(1<<SS);
    SPDR = data;
    while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
    PORTB |= (1<<SS);
    return (SPDR);
}
```

**Try to start the slave before master is started!**